# Which function is there in Python equivalent to Val() in VB6?

Tags: python, python-2.7, vb6

I'm converting some programs from Visual Basic 6.0 to Python, and I'm stuck in one line in VB.

Visual Basic code:

```vb
bAddStart = "100"
bNoOfBytes = "94"
MeterId = 1

Data = Chr(MeterId) + Chr(3) + Chr(Val(bAddStart) \ 256) + Chr(Val(bAddStart) Mod 256) + Chr(0) + Chr(Val(bNoOfBytes))
```

For the function `Chr` in VB I'm using `chr()` in Python.
For the `Val` function, which is a similar function in Python?

Comment: float(expression) possibly?

Comment: The Val function in VB 6 is more complicated than it might seem. It is quite possible that there is no exact equivalent in Python. I suggest that you consider the data  type of bAddStart and bNoOfBytes and what values they might contain. Then choose Python code that will reliably convert those values to numbers that can be used in your expression. I see that you say the variables are strings. In that case you might also want to validate them before attempting to convert to numbers.

Comment: Rather than translating *"word by word"* you might be better figuring out if there's an entirely better approach available in Python.

Comment: According to the docs for `Val()` it handles octals and hex values indicated by `&O` and `&H` respectively. this is not how octals and hex values are indicated in Python (`0o` and `0x`) so you will have to decide if you want to accept the valid input in the VB style or the Python style or if you want to be able to handle both.

Comment: `Val()` is also locale-blind, i.e. it always accepts *invariant locale* number punctuation (decimal point is always the period character) even when the process locale uses something else (e.g. comma).

Answer (score 1):

There is **no inbuilt function** in python that is equivalent to ***[Val()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9da280t0%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)***. You will have to *implement your own function*. I used this code when I ran into a similar problem before  -

```
def val(data):
    y=0
    nst=""
    dlist = ['0','1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9']
    for x in data:
        for i in dlist:
            if x == i:
                nst=nst+x
    n=len(nst)
    dcont=n
    acum=0
    for z in range(n):
        y=0
        for i in dlist:
            if nst[z] == i:
                d=y
                mult=1
                dcont=dcont-1
                for j in range(dcont):
                    mult=mult*10
                acum=acum+(d*mult)
            y=y+1

    return acum
```

Comment: Your second function returns `0` for the input `" 1234 123th Street N.E."` when according to the docs it should return `'1234123'`

Answer (score 0):

try `int(bNoOfBytes)`

e.g: `chr(int("65"))` will return `A`.

Comment: I know chr() function in python... tell me Val() function in python...?

Comment: I've already mentioned it: use `int`. The `int` constructor tries to convert the string argument into an integer. Beware, if the integer is greater than 255 (or negative), `chr` will raise. As an example for the VB code you posted, its python translation would assign to `Data` the value: `\x01\x03\x00d\x00^`

Answer (score 0):

if we use int() function as below, you will get the perfect answer.

```
    str_no = "12345"
    no = int(str_no) * 1
    print(no)
    print(no + 1)
```